# rviz not launching with MoveIt config launch file

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

System: Virtualbox VM
Linux: Ubuntu 16.04
ROS: Kinetic

I am following the tutorials on using MoveIt with ROS. I have tried 2 tutorials both [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html) and [here](https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/kinetic/_source/session3/Build-a-Moveit!-Package.html).

The problem occurs in both tutorials after creating the MoveIt config file and attempting to launch it with `roslaunch`:

```
roslaunch myworkcell_moveit_config myworkcell_planning_execution.launch
```

The Rviz splashscreen shows up with the initialising status but does not progress from this. There is an error about the planner:

```
[ERROR] [1560344053.702727103]: Could not find the planner configuration 'None' on the param server
```

It even states in the terminal:

> You can start planning now.

I am able to run `rviz` fine on its own with:

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

The rest of the output in the terminal is as follows:

`

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /joint_state_publisher/source_list: ['move_group/fake...
 * /joint_state_publisher/use_gui: False
 * /move_group/allow_trajectory_execution: True
 * /move_group/capabilities: 
 * /move_group/controller_list: [{'joints': ['joi...
 * /move_group/disable_capabilities: 
 * /move_group/jiggle_fraction: 0.05
 * /move_group/manipulator/default_planner_config: None
 * /move_group/manipulator/longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.005
 * /move_group/manipulator/planner_configs: ['SBL', 'EST', 'L...
 * /move_group/manipulator/projection_evaluator: joints(joint_a1,j...
 * /move_group/max_range: 5.0
 * /move_group/max_safe_path_cost: 1
 * /move_group/moveit_controller_manager: moveit_fake_contr...
 * /move_group/moveit_manage_controllers: True
 * /move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.025
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/balanced: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/cache_cc: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/extended_fmt: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/heuristics: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/nearest_k: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/num_samples: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/optimality: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/type: geometric::BFMT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/type: geometric::BKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiEST/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiEST/type: geometric::BiEST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/cost_threshold: 1e300
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/frountier_node_ratio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/init_temperature: 100
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/temp_change_factor: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/type: geometric::BiTRRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/EST/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/EST/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/EST/type: geometric::EST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/cache_cc: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/extended_fmt: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/heuristics: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/nearest_k: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/num_samples: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/radius_multiplier: 1.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/FMT/type: geometric::FMT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/type: geometric::KPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/type: geometric::LBKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/epsilon: 0.4
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/type: geometric::LBTRRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRM/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRM/type: geometric::LazyPRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMstar/type: geometric::LazyPR...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PDST/type: geometric::PDST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRM/max_nearest_neighbors: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRM/type: geometric::PRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMstar/type: geometric::PRMstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjEST/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjEST/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ProjEST/type: geometric::ProjEST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRT/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRT/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRT/type: geometric::RRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnect/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnect/type: geometric::RRTCon...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/delay_collision_checking: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/type: geometric::RRTstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBL/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBL/type: geometric::SBL
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/max_failures: 1000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/type: geometric::SPARS
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/max_failures: 5000
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/type: geometric::SPARStwo
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/degree: 16
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/estimated_dimension: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/max_degree: 18
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/max_pts_per_leaf: 6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/min_degree: 12
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.2
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/type: geometric::STRIDE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/use_projected_distance: 0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/frountierNodeRatio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/init_temperature: 10e-6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/k_constant: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/max_states_failed: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/min_temperature: 10e-10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/temp_change_factor: 2.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/type: geometric::TRRT
 * /move_group/planning_plugin: ompl_interface/OM...
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates: True
 * /move_group/request_adapters: default_planner_r...
 * /move_group/sensors: [{'point_subsampl...
 * /move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error: 0.1
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 1.2
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.5
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_start_tolerance: 0.01
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_description_kinematics/manipulator/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /robot_description_kinematics/manipulator/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /robot_description_kinematics/manipulator/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /robot_description_kinematics/manipulator/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a1/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a1/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a1/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a1/max_velocity: 2.72271363311
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a2/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a2/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a2/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a2/max_velocity: 2.72271363311
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a3/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a3/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a3/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a3/max_velocity: 2.72271363311
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a4/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a4/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a4/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a4/max_velocity: 5.75958653158
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a5/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a5/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a5/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a5/max_velocity: 5.75958653158
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a6/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a6/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a6/max_acceleration: 0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint_a6/max_velocity: 10.7337748998
 * /robot_description_semantic: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /rviz_talha_VirtualBox_2209_1189131161637441768/manipulator/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /rviz_talha_VirtualBox_2209_1189131161637441768/manipulator/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /rviz_talha_VirtualBox_2209_1189131161637441768/manipulator/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /rviz_talha_VirtualBox_2209_1189131161637441768/manipulator/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005

NODES
  /
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz_talha_VirtualBox_2209_1189131161637441768 (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [2226]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [2227]
process[move_group-3]: started with pid [2228]
[ WARN] [1560344053.452253758]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
process[rviz_talha_VirtualBox_2209_1189131161637441768-4]: started with pid [2249]
[ INFO] [1560344053.496640076]: Loading robot model 'kuka_kr16_2'...
[ INFO] [1560344053.570688196]: Loading robot model 'kuka_kr16_2'...
[ WARN] [1560344053.574339033]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[ INFO] [1560344053.575414819]: rviz version 1.12.17
[ INFO] [1560344053.575455888]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1560344053.575467911]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1560344053.613958606]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1560344053.617565517]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
Starting context monitors...
[ INFO] [1560344053.617611959]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1560344053.621063575]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1560344053.621105594]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1560344053.624478374]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/base_link '
[ INFO] [1560344053.627665820]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ INFO] [1560344053.671201746]: Listening to '/head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points' using message filter with target frame '/base_link '
[ INFO] [1560344053.677909803]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
Context monitors started.
[ INFO] [1560344053.697808790]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ERROR] [1560344053.702727103]: Could not find the planner configuration 'None' on the param server
[ INFO] [1560344053.730134588]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ INFO] [1560344053.735427908]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10
[ INFO] [1560344053.736112214]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1560344053.736775365]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1560344053.737461052]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1560344053.738201938]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1560344053.738845543]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1560344053.738943580]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Parameterization'
[ INFO] [1560344053.738979920]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1560344053.739012586]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1560344053.739172871]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1560344053.739207349]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[ INFO] [1560344053.742072959]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1560344053.742138831]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ INFO] [1560344053.749284081]: Fake controller 'fake_manipulator_controller' with joints [ joint_a1 joint_a2 joint_a3 joint_a4 joint_a5 joint_a6 ]
[ INFO] [1560344053.750216084]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1560344053.775381406]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1560344053.864494438]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1560344053.864554545]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1560344053.864575536]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!

`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325487/rviz-not-launching-with-moveit-config-launch-file/) by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2019-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: Just found out that I had been running a `roscore` hidden behind the many terminal windows which was the culprit. The launch file for the MoveIt config launches its own master so there probably is a conflict there. Just tested with the original `ompl_planning.yaml` file and it ran fine although still gave the error `could not find the planner configuration 'None' on the param server` but that is probably a non-issue.

---

Originally posted by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) with karma: 61 on 2019-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
Which version of MoveIt are you using? Afaik this has been fixed quite some time ago, so either the MoveIt configuration is outdated, or the MoveIt version you are using.

**Comment by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on 2019-06-12**:
0.9.15. Apparently the latest version under kinetic when running the command `apt install ros-kinetic-moveit`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
And where did you get the moveit configuration package?

**Comment by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on 2019-06-12**:
Generated myself using the setup assistant as in the tutorials

**Comment by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on 2019-06-12**:
Just updated answer above

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
So there was essentially no real problem then?

**Comment by [mt](https://answers.ros.org/users/42562/mt/) on 2019-06-12**:
No. Just my oversight